# Add mouse right click option in Mac OS X like windows

Tags: macos

I have requirement to add mouse right click option in folder or file list like windows explorer. Requirement is like below:

"There are some files with particular extension showed in Finder/folder list in Mac OS X. When user click on file with that particular extension I need to show my .exe or .app name which can open that file".

I want to know how to achieve this functionality in Mac OS X. In windows it is game of registry but I am not sure how to achieve same in Mac OS X.

Comment: It is ok if I can have my application name in "Open With" section. First preference is I will have my application in first level of right click menu. After click on my application it is required how to pass that file name to my application. I am searching some option related to Services under Finder. Let me know if I am in wrong direction

Answer (score 1):

You get this in the Info.plist file in your app bundle by specifying file extensions your application can open in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107

Answer (score 0):

I tried that option. It is working fine and I am getting my application icon with that extension file and also my application is there in Default handler. But now issue is that this application I have created thru Qt and in main function of my application I am getting only application path in argv and argc and not the selected file. So let me know how to achieve this. If more information is required then please let me know. Thank you for valueable answer